# How to remove querystring from a url via web.config

Tags: c#, asp.net, redirect

I need 301 redirect for all urls like

> xyz.com/searchitems?key1=val1&key2=val2 to be like
>
> xyz.com/searchitems

i.e. I want query string to be removed from URL. I have written this so far in my `web.config`

```
        <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="Rewrite to searchitems">
          <match url="^searchitems?$" />
<conditions>
    <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="(.*)" />
  </conditions>
          <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Permanent" url="{R:0}" appendQueryString="false"  />
        </rule>
      </rules>
   </rewrite>
```

but it is making redirect loop

Edit:

I wat the querystring to be removed just for this url "xyz.com/searchitems" and not for all urls. There can be any number of query string params in urls.

Comment: "?" needs to be escaped in regular expressions. Currently, your rule matches the URL "searchitem" since the trailing "s" is turned optional by the "?". If the "?" had been a literal part of the URL, maybe there wouldn't be a redirect loop since the resulting URL has no "?" in it. :)

Comment: I tried this too <match url="^searchresults$" />

Comment: I guess the pattern to match searchresults only with some params is `"^(.*searchitems)\?.+$"`

Comment: It is not even matching now and just opening xyz.com/searchitems?key1=val1&key2=val2

Comment: Unit test it with something like this :
`Regex r = new Regex(@"^(.*searchitems)\?.+$");
 
 var b1 = r.IsMatch("xyz.com/searchitems?qsdfj=qsdkfj%20");
 var b2 = r.IsMatch("xyz.com/searchitems?key1=val1&key2=val2");
 var b3 = r.IsMatch("xyz.com/searchitems");
 var b4 = r.Matches("xyz.com/searchitems?qsdfj=qsdkfj%20");`

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
  <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="Custom rule" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="^searchitems" />
          <conditions>
            <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="(.+)" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Redirect" url="/searchitems" appendQueryString="false" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
```